# Having trouble running valgrind in a docker container inside a Kali VM

Tags: c, linux, docker, valgrind

Im trying to test a C program that prints chars and handles escape characters to stdout in docker. Im running docker in a kali linux VM. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

WORKDIR /Lab3

COPY . .

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm && pacman -S --noconfirm base-devel

RUN pacman -S --noconfirm valgrind

RUN chmod +x testscr.sh

CMD ["./testscr.sh"]
```

when I run my code in kali, I end up with a normal result. When I run it in docker, valgrind gives me this error:

```
valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:  
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

This entire project is just for experimenting with/learning docker, I already know the code works and there are no memory leaks. Why is valgrind failing?

I tried rebuilding and making sure nested virtualization is enabled. The output for the program without valgrind is as expected.

Comment: Well, don't use docker. I've seen problems that docker's inadequate virtualisation causes. I've yet to see anything that works better with docker. Possibly, though, this has already been fixed https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=473745

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are running Docker on a Kali Linux system. Your `Dockerfile` is using an Arch Linux base image but you don't mention that you specifically need this distribution. Try this with an Ubuntu base image.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /Lab3

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y -qq g++ valgrind

# Copy files AFTER pacman install, otherwise cached install not used.
#
COPY . .

RUN chmod +x testscr.sh

CMD ["./testscr.sh"]
```

`testscr.sh` (I don't know what this looks like, do guessing here...)

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ -g -o leaky leaky.cpp
valgrind --leak-check=full ./leaky
```

`leaky.cpp` (A simple C++ file with memory leak.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

// This has a memory leak!

int main() {
    int *ptr = new int; // Allocate memory without deallocating it.
    *ptr = 10;
    std::cout << "Value: " << *ptr << std::endl;
    // delete ptr; // Uncomment this line to fix the memory leak
    return 0;
}
```

[image]